# Local Component is not recognized

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to use hooks and just functional components. In the scenario below, the local Component that I have on the same page is not recognized when i use it:

```
import React from "react";

const LocalComp = () => {
  return <div>test<div/>;
}; 

const MianComp = () => { 
  return (
    <div>
     <LocalComp />
    </div>
  );
};

export default MianComp ;
```

It works when i used to do in class-based components, but can I handle it now in the same page?, or do I have to separate the local on and import it?

Comment: Define "not recognized"; it shouldn't matter where the components are defined, or whether they're class- or function-based.

Comment: it's graded out.

Comment: wooooooow, damn it, I should use capital letters :| sorry for the time wasting